# Java ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, bukkit

I'm attempting to read a certain file in Java and make it into a multidimensional array. Whenever I read a line of code from the script, The console says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I know that this error is caused when the coding can't reach the specific index, but I have no idea how to fix it at the moment.

Here is an example of my coding.

```
int x = 1;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  //Explode string line
  String[] Guild = line.split("\\|");
  //Add that value to the guilds array
  for (int i = 0; i < Guild.length; i++) {
    ((ArrayList)guildsArray.get(x)).add(Guild[i]);
    if(sender.getName().equals(Guild[1])) {
      //The person is the owner of Guild[0]
      ownerOfGuild = Guild[0];
    }
  }
  x++;
}
```

**Text Document **

```
Test|baseman101|baseman101|0|
Test2|Player2|Player2|0|
```

Other solutions, such as the one found here: [Write to text file without overwriting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961292/write-to-text-file-without-overwriting-in-java)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, Exception says what's happening at Exception level. Array is size 1 and you access position 1. Your logic is not ok!

Comment: I thought ArrayLists increase dynamically?

Comment: They do increase dinamically, however they're 0 based and accessing to a bigger index than the actual one will result in an Exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

problem 1 -> `int x = 1;`
solution: The x should be start with 0

problem 2->

```
((ArrayList)guildsArray.get(x)).add(Guild[i]);
```

You are increasing  `x`  so `if x >= guildsArray.size()` then you will get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

solution

```
if( x >= guildsArray.size())
      guildsArray.add(new ArrayList());
for (int i = 0; i < Guild.length; i++) {
    ((ArrayList)guildsArray.get(x)).add(Guild[i]);
    if(sender.getName().equals(Guild[1])) {
      //The person is the owner of Guild[0]
      ownerOfGuild = Guild[0];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring here:

```
... guildsArray.get(x) ...
```

but is caused here:

```
int x = 1;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   ...
```

Because Collections and arrays are zero-based (the first element is index `0`).

Try this:

```
int x = 0;
```