# Android : Can't get the index 1 on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I know this question sounds stupid for several members here, but i have no idea anymore.

I faced a strange problem with array. I try to get the `index 1` on `ArrayList` but it always throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` .

I have debug by the following code :

```
for (int o=0; o<vcard.size(); o++){
    if(vcard.get(o).contains(":")){
        System.out.println("Contains");
        String[] splitByTitikDuaVCard = vcard.get(o).split(Pattern.quote(":"));
        //this line show the length is 2 
        System.out.println("RESULT LENGTH : " + splitByTitikDuaVCard.length );
        for (int y=0; y<splitByTitikDuaVCard.length; y++){
            System.out.println("RESULT Y : " + splitByTitikDuaVCard[y] + ", INDEX : " + y);
            mapContentTerbaruVCard.put(splitByTitikDuaVCard[0], splitByTitikDuaVCard[1]);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Contains");
    }
}
```

The result of the `log` :

```
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : BEGIN, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : VCARD, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : VERSION, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : 3.0, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : N, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : Doe;John, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : FN, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : John Doe, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : ORG, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : PT. Pertamina, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : TITLE, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : Bussiness Manager, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : ADR, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : ;;Soekarno Hatta;Bandung;;46153;West Jave, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : TEL;WORK;VOICE, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : 021 203312, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 2
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : TEL;CELL, INDEX : 0
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : +62818456463111, INDEX : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 1
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT Y : TEL;FAX, INDEX : 0
```

The `log` show that the `index 1` is exist, but when i try to put the `index 1` into `HashMap`, the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` is appears

My Question is : **How to find the `index 1` so i can save it into `hashmap`**

Note : i have try this ([Java ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 1, Size: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462184/java-arraylist-indexoutofboundsexception-index-1-size-1)) solution but not working on my case.

Comment: The error tells you that the size of the ArrayList is 1. The index of the only element is therefore 0.

Comment: "The log show that the index 1 is exist" Please show this log. Also, you should give a complete code example. Be sure to include put your code inside a method which is inside a class. Finally, post the entire stacktrace and show us which line causes the error.

Comment: Arrays start counting from 0. Basically what the error message tells you is the following: You have an array/arraylist which has 1 element and you tried to access the element at index 1 which is actually the second element in your list. (or is not since you got an error).

Comment: Saying "i have try this..." is not sufficient. Your code will never be exactly the same as the code given in the link. This means you need to show us **exactly** what you tried so that we can help you from there.

Comment: @code-Apprentice : in case, i have split the string by `:`. it should be contains two index = `index 0` and `index 1`. correct me please

Comment: all : i have posted the result of the log

Comment: See my updated answer and you'll understand.

Comment: See my second comment above.

Comment: i have updated my post, sir. please check it.

Comment: Look closely at your log.

Answer (score 0):

`splitByTitikDuaVCard` may have `lenght = 1`, so position `[1]` is out of its bounds.

For OP, try it yourself. You'll notice the length is 1.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      final String[] splitted = "String:".split(":");
      System.out.println(splitted.length);
   }
}
```

Lookint at your log:

```
03-08 23:00:18.594 8350-8350/? I/System.out: RESULT LENGTH : 1
```

length = **1**

Comment: but i have split it by `:`, it should be contains 2 index therefore `index 0` and `index 1`, please corrent me.

Comment: @Koma See updated answer, it will explain what may happen.

Comment: no sir. i do `String[] splitByTitikDuaVCard = vcard.get(o).split(Pattern.quote(":"));` and `System.out.println("RESULT LENGTH : " + splitByTitikDuaVCard.length );` the length show `2`

Comment: It's impossible. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: See updated answer. Last record of your log shows length = 1. So my guess is right.

Answer (score -1):

In Second Loop (Inner loop) you are getting value from `splitByTitikDuaVCard[1]` why you are putting value of indexes hardcoded. you should use the value of y.

Replace this

```
mapContentTerbaruVCard.put(splitByTitikDuaVCard[0], splitByTitikDuaVCard[1]);
```

With this

```
mapContentTerbaruVCard.put("key"+y, splitByTitikDuaVCard[y]);
```

in this code your key will be **key0, key1, ....**

Try this code it will help you

Comment: what exactly "key" means?. I my case i need to save the `index 0` of `splitByTitikDuaVCard` as the `key` into `hasmap`

Comment: **key** is the identification for value in `HashMap`. You don't know the **value** in `HashMap` but you know the key, then you can easily found the value of specific **key**. And yes store index as a key so you can get value from index. But do not store **hard-coded** value. see my answer again.